# Why Odoo performance is too slow while loading huge data?

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo, odoo-10

I have large data to import but after imported the same odoo performing very slow.

I have import around 3,00,000 customer and also other millions of data.
Once imported the all datas odoo being very slow.

Can anyone let me know how to resolve this?

Comment: This is not a programming question, and is offtopic on stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

No single bullet for solve that, specially a performance issue. Could be related to a lot of stuffs. Try to identify the queries that blocks or took too long to complete. Try to add/fix the needed postgresql indexes involved in those queries. Also identify the code involved in the slow request/queries. You could search for some perf tools like profilers to be able to bring light into that